# Is there an easy way to read a .md (markdown) file as a character vector into R

Tags: r, nlp, r-markdown, markdown, text-mining

I have a raw markdown file that I have taken from online, and I want to read the text into R as a character vector. Is there a good way of doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by reading it line by line? Will `readLines` suffice?

Comment: I am going to run some NLP on the text data, the `readLines` function does the job nicely. Thank you.

Comment: @mhovd, post as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read (most) files line by line using `readLines`, which should also work for markdown. Take a look at the [documentation.](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/readLines)

You specify the file to read using the `con` argument, e.g.

```r
readLines(con = "markdown.md")
```